# Laravel and multiple queues (AWS SQS)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs

I'm stuck on dispatching jobs into multiple SQS queues using `onQueue('queuename')`.

The queue names on SQS have prefixes to distinct projects.
It seems that hardcoding each queue name of SQS is not the best way do that. I think that there should be something like an aliases map in `queue.php` config file.

Is there a known practice to deal with that properly?

Comment: Improved question's formatting for better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it came VERY useful define the queue name as a combination of **Environment Name** and **Project Queue Name**

Using CloudFormation I create the queue like

```
QueueName:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    VisibilityTimeout: 120
    QueueName: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'ProjectQueueName']]
    Tags:
      - Key: Stack
        Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
```

In this way whenever you want to push something in a queue you'll just do

```
MyJob::dispatch($payload)->onQueue(env('APP_ENV').'ProjectQueueName');
```

or, if you want to define the queue name in the `.env` file too,

```
MyJob::dispatch($payload)->onQueue(env('APP_ENV').env('ProjectQueueName'));
```

And just to be a little more precise, in the `queue.php` you define the connection and the default queue, but no map alias, that would be quite useful, to be honest, but there is nothing like that yet, as far as I know